# creating a new table everyday according to date in sql

Tags: php, mysql, date, database-design

This is code for creating table everyday according to date. But new table is  not created in database. Help me with this, please. The code is below:

```
$date = date ('Ymd');
echo $date;

$query = "CREATE TABLE TEST_" . $date;
$query .= " (Name text(20), Class int(5), Age int(3), Date date, created CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: actually i want to create new table simultaneously in my database.But i have to write sql query to create table each time i am running this code.Got it?

Comment: But we still don't know why. This is a very strange thing to want to do (well, in the context of an RDBMS anyway )

Comment: While I concur with Strawberry, this shouldn't be done, did you execute your query or just add it to a variable?

Comment: why is it strange?coz m gonna keep track of records in new table everyday.So it'll be easy for me to search my data according to date

Comment: That's what `WHERE date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'` is for...

Comment: It actually makes it harder to search by date if you separate your tables by day, unless you'll only ever want to search for one particular day at a time. Using a date column is just as easy, though.

Comment: There's absolutely no good reason to do what you're trying to do. Just keep it all in one table.

Comment: creating a new table every day is plain wrong. you should *not* do that. never. instead, you chould create *one* table with a date-field. with that, you can simply filter with `WHERE date = :thedayyouwant` - but trust me, with one table every day, you *will* run into tons and tons of problems - you *will* regret it.

Answer (score 0):

**Without Concat you can directy pass**

```
$date = date ('Ymd');
$query = "CREATE TABLE tbltable_'".$date."' (
Name varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Class int,
Age int,
Date date,
created CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";
mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Why would you recommend the use of mysql_query?

Comment: check question tag he is using php

Comment: Do you realize that all `mysql_*` functions have been removed from PHP 7+ and should not be used anymore?

Comment: Yes mysqli is not the same as mysql_* functions.